# Paypal Pay Now Button

Tags: paypal

Been looking at the PayPal API documentation, there is so much to look it i thought i would ask here to get a more clear answer from someone that's done similar.

I'm looking to add a 'pay now' PayPal button to invoices that are generated by users within a web app for their customers. So a payment should never reach me at all. I understand that the button is probably the best option however it will need to be the encrypted button to be more secure.

I understand i need to use my PayPal account to be able to access the API and generate these encrypted buttons? it's literally just a matter of setting the item, cost and business parameters really, I don't want any transaction hitting my account.

What are my options? and is this even possible.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you're familiar with web service API's skip the standard buttons altogether and just go with the [Pay API](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/adaptive-payments/Pay_API_Operation/).

That will allow users to easily pay by signing in to a PayPal or using a credit card (guest checkout).  In most cases users would be authenticating the payment during checkout, but you could also tie in the ability for people to use Preapproval profiles so that future payments are automatic (or one-click, or whatever you want.)  You use the [Preapproval API](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/adaptive-payments/Preapproval_API_Operation/) to generate a preapproval key for the user, and then future Pay requests can include that key for immediate payment without further authentication.

If you're working with PHP my [class library for PayPal](http://www.angelleye.com/download-angell-eye-php-class-library-for-paypal/) will make this very simple for you.